# Python Cookielib with HTTP Servers that Have Incorrect Date / Timezone Set

Tags: python, date, http, cookies, urllib2

I am using python and `cookielib` to talk to an HTTP server that has its date incorrectly set. I have no control over this server, so fixing its time is not a possibility. Unfortunately, the server's incorrect time messes up `cookielib` because the cookies appear to be expired.

Interestingly, if I go to the same website with any web browser, the browser accepts the cookie and it gets saved. I assume that modern webbrowsers come across misconfigured web servers all the time and see that their `Date` header is set incorrectly, and adjust cookie expiration dates accordingly.

Has anyone come across this problem before? Is there any way of handling it within Python?

[image: bad server date]

Answer (score 0):

I hacked together a solution that includes live-monkey patching of the urllib library. Definitely not ideal, but if others find a better way, please let me know:

```
cook_proc = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookielib.LWPCookieJar())
cookie_processing_lock = threading.Lock()

def _process_cookies(request, response):
    '''Process cookies, but do so in a way that can handle servers with bad 
    clocks set.'''
    # We do some real monkey hacking here, so put it in a lock.
    with cookie_processing_lock:
        # Get the server date.
        date_header = cookielib.http2time(
            response.info().getheader('Date') or '')
        # Save the old cookie parsing function.
        orig_parse = cookielib.parse_ns_headers
        # If the server date is off by more than an hour, we'll adjust it.
        if date_header:
            off_by = time.time() - date_header
            if abs(off_by) > 3600:
                logging.warning("Server off %.1f hrs."%(abs(off_by)/3600))
                # Create our monkey patched
                def hacked_parse(ns_headers):
                    try:
                        results = orig_parse(ns_headers)
                        for r in results:
                            for r_i, (key, val) in enumerate(r):
                                if key == 'expires':
                                    r[r_i] = key, val + off_by
                                    logging.info("Fixing bad cookie "
                                        "expiration time for: %s"%r[0][0])
                        logging.info("COOKIE RESULTS: %s", results)
                        return results
                    except Exception as e:
                        logging.error("Problem parse cookie: %s"%e)
                        raise
                cookielib.parse_ns_headers = hacked_parse
        response = cook_proc.http_response(request, response)
        # Make sure we set the cookie processor back.
        cookielib.parse_ns_headers = orig_parse
```